# can't find react native start to run the app on ios

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

After init the Demo App, I try to run on the simulator.When I open the Command-Shift-P, I can't find the react native start command. Is there any packages need to be installed?
[image]

Comment: Did you try `react-native start`? Make sure you have installed all dependencies.

Comment: of course ,react-native start is no matches found as well. The Nuclide menu doesn't include the react native item...Could you tell me which dependency? I have Checked the  nuclide settings  Install recommended packages on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I found the answer.
packager was renamed to metro at some point, try 'metro start' instead

https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/1392